# space/tab/newline insensitive comparison

Tags: string, bash, shell, comparison, diff

Suppose I have these two files:

File 1:
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

File 2:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Is it possible to use `diff` to compare these two files so that the result is `equal` ?

(Or if not, what are other tools should I use? )

Thanks

Comment: Convert newlines(or maybe `\s+\r+`) to spaces and then check?

Comment: Does `diff -w` (which is the same as `diff --ignore-all-space`) help?

Answer (score 2):

You could collapse whitespace so `file2` looks like `file1`, with every number on the same line:

```
$ cat file1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
$ cat file2
1
2
4
3
5
6
7
$ diff <(echo $(< file1)) <(echo $(< file2))
1c1
< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
---
> 1 2 4 3 5 6 7
```

Explanation:

```
< file             # Equivalent to "cat file", but slightly faster since the shell doesn't
                   #     have to fork a new process.

$(< file)          # Capture the output of the "< file" command. Can also be written
                   #     with backticks, as in `< file`.

echo $(< file)     # Echo each word from the file. This will have the side effect of
                   #     collapsing all of the whitespace.

<(echo $(< file))  # An advanced way of piping the output of one command to another.
                   #     The shell opens an unused file descriptor (say fd 42) and pipes
                   #     the echo command to it. Then it passes the filename /dev/fd/42 to
                   #     diff. The result is that you can pipe two different echo commands
                   #     to diff.
```

Alternately, you may want to make `file1` look like `file2`, with each number on separate lines. That will produce more useful diff output.

```
$ diff -u <(printf '%s\n' $(< file1)) <(printf '%s\n' $(< file2))
--- /dev/fd/63  2012-09-10 23:55:30.000000000 -0400
+++ file2   2012-09-10 23:47:24.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 1
 2
-3
 4
+3
 5
 6
 7
```

This is similar to the first command with `echo` changed to `printf '%s\n'` to put a newline after each word.

**Note:** Both of these commands will fail if the files being diffed are overly long. This is because of the limit on command-line length. If that happens then you will need to workaround this limitation, say by storing the output of echo/printf to temporary files.

Comment: Normalizing to newlines would produce a neater diff. `diff <(tr -s ' \t' '\n' <file1) <(tr -s ' \t' '\n' <file2)`

Answer (score 1):

Some diffs have a `-b` (ignore blanks) and `-w` (ingnore whitespace), but as unix utilities are all line-oriented, I don't thing whitespace will include `\n` chars.

Dbl-check that your version of `diff` doesn't have some fancy gnu-options with `diff --help | less` or `man diff`.

Is your formatting correct above, file 1, data all on one line? You could force file2 to match that format with

```
awk '{printf"%s ", $0}' file2
```

Or as mentioned in comments, convert file 1

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s\n", $i)}' file1
```

But I'm guessing that your data isn't really that simple. Also there are likely line length limitations that will appear when you can least afford the time to deal with them.

Probably not what you want to hear, and `diff`ing of complicated stuff like source-code is not an exact science. So, if you still need help, create a slightly more complicated testcase and add it to your question.

Finally, you'll need to show us what you'd expect the output of such a diff project to look like. Right now I can't see any meaningful way to display such differences for a non-trival case. 
IHTH

Answer (score 1):

If it turns out the data is indeed simple enough to not run into limitations, and the only difference between the files is that the first one separates by space and the second by newline, you can also do process substitution (as was suggested above) but with sed to replace the spaces in the first file with newlines:

```shell
diff <(sed 's/ /\n/g' file1) file2
```